# evaluate volume with triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A volcano fills the volume between the graphs $z=0$ and $z=1/(x^2+y^2)^9 $, and outside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ Find the volume of this volcano.

I cannot even write down the integral. What should i do?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should show your work. You stated what you cannot so.  But so show what you *have* been able to so so we can help you with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice problem. 
Hints: 
Use polar coordinates. This becomes an integral in 1 variable. The upper limit of the integral is infinity.

The volume of a thin shell at a distance r from the origin is $2 \pi r z dr$ where $z=z(r)$ is the height of the volcano at that radius $r$. This is what you need to integrate form he lower limit of r to infinity.

The integral is simple. If you want to check answers, I got the volume to be π/8.